# How to interpret this model diagnostics?

Tags: mixed-model, data-transformation, residuals, diagnostic, bounds

A model was fit as below:

```
m1 <- lmer(log (ld50) ~ var * strain * time + (1|rep) + (1|rep:var) + (1|strain:env), dt)
```

The response **ld50** ranges from 0.15 (lower bound) to 93.77 (upper bound). There are several datapoints at these bounds.

The residual plots look like this:

[image: Model diagnostics]

**What is the best way to transform the dataset? What is happening here?**

Answer (score 0):

I believe the straight lines in the residual plot are common when the IVs are all categorical.

The QQ plot shows some extremely high and low residuals (this would be even more apparent if the axes had the same scale, personally, I think that the default here is a mistake).

The index plot shows nothing interesting.

The histogram shows the same thing as the QQ plot, and also that there are a lot of residuals that are close to 0 (good predictions), although what "close" means is field dependent (here, I think a box plot would be better ...., but that's me).

What to do?

I don't think transformation is the answer. I think you need to look at the cases with very high or low residuals and figure out what's going on. Possibly there is an omitted variable that would help. Or maybe there is some problem in the data (I believe it was David Cox who said, near the end of his career, that he had never seen a data set entered 100% correctly).

You could also think about a nonlinear multilevel model. In that case, I wouldn't even take the log of LD50, unless there are *substantive* reasons for doing so.